# How do you serialise Map<Number, Object> or Map<LocalDate, Object> into XML with Jackson?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

It appears as if Jackson (2.9, current version as of writing) cannot serialize Java data structures like

- `Map<Integer, Object>`
- `Map<LocalData, Object>`
- `Map<Double, Object>`

into valid XML. The issue is that a `Map<K,V>` is represented as

```
<Map>
  <key1>
    value1
  </key1>
  <key2>
    value2
  </key2>
</Map>
```

and XML tags are not allowed to start with numbers (this also excludes 2019-04-27).

How do I have to configure Jackson to serialise a Map or any DTO containing a Map into a valid XML?

(Note: a similar problem is an option issue https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/244 on since 2017).

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Ask yourself, what do you want the XML to be? If you don't know the goal, it's almost impossible to get there. --- E.g. do you want `<Entry><key>xx</key><value>yy</value></Entry>`? Or `<Entry key="xx">yy</Entry>`? Or, if value is a single value, not a complex object, `<Entry key="xx" value="yy"/>`? Or, if value is an object that is rendered to an XML element, `<Entry><key>xx</key><yy>...</yy></Entry>`?

Comment: For me ``<Entry><key>xx</key><value>yy</value></Entry>`` or ``<Entry key="xx">yy</Entry>`` would be a both preferable solutions. But how can I tell Jackson to do so? The default settings of Jackson generate ill-formed XML. If only only of the two is possible with Jackson it would be fine for me - so I am not asking for a specific solution.